Is it possible to view multiple run/edit configurations in IntelliJ-based products or create shortcuts for them?
Currently, I can only see a single run configuration at a time without opening the edit window:

However, in addition to running my project, I've added other useful scripts that I need to invoke while debugging:

To run these scripts, I need to switch to each one and then execute it. This requires constantly switching back and forth. Is there a way to view multiple run configurations together in the main window and invoke them without switching between them? Is there perhaps a hidden feature or a plugin that enables this functionality?

While not exactly what you're asking for, you might find the Run Anything feature useful.
From the docs: "Run Anything is a quick way to launch run/debug configurations, applications, scripts, commands, tasks, and open recent projects."
You can open the Run Anything popup by pressing ⌃Ctrl twice (on macOS), or Ctrl twice (on Windows/Linux) and then type the name of the Run configuration you want to run.
Note that the Run Anything popup will be empty at first, but will be populated with "recent" runs. Once you've ran the desired Run Configurations, they will be in the "recent" list, and you can navigate to them using the arrow keys and pressing enter to select and run them.
If this is not what you're looking for, have a look at Is it possible to run multiple applications in IntelliJ with just one press of a button?

Thank you, I will check it tomorrow. It was a tough week.
